# How to read passive RFID cards using Android?

Tags: android

I am working on Android application (Droid Incredible).

I am planning to read passive RFID tags using Android phone but I found that there is no slot for Android to connect to RFID reader.

After some research, I found out that I will have to get RFID reader which can send RF data over bluetooth to Android. 
But I am not sure which company manufactures it or what will be cost of such RFID reader.

Is there any one who can help me or throw some light on this issue?

Thanks
Siddhesh

Comment: You may be able to intergrate with a bluetooth RFID reader.

Comment: Thanks Matthew, but can you tell me which company manufactures a bluetooth RFID reader for Android? I saw one video on youtube where in RFID tags are read using some stick reader.

Comment: What is a "passive RFID tag"?

Comment: check this post https://stackoverflow.com/a/63374277/4797289

Answer (score 1):

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=COKHnnWRYSg they say it's android compatible

Answer (score 0):

Inorder to read RFID Passive tags using Android devices, Now there are Android devices with RFID integrated in it to read the Passive tags and you can customize your android application according to your requirement

If you want to build your own circuit for reading Passive tags and to get the tag data to your Android device, The best way is to use Arduino Microcontroller Boards. Using **EM-18 and RC- 522 RFID** modules integrated with Arduino, you can read the **LF and HF Passive tags** respectively. If tag reads, you can get the data either in serial monitor or display attached to the Arduino.
To get this RFID tag data to the Android device, the circuit which helps you is HC-05 Bluetooth Module which sends/receive to/from Android device.

Thanks

Answer (score -1):

Siddhesh:

RFID is supported since Android 2.3 (GingerBread) but with an exception (if the brand handset has available the hardware to do that). On the most of the cases you can check on handset's cover a label like as NFC and so on.

I understand is established by RF (HF) and its purpose is to replace: bar codes, QR codes and bluetooth and it looks like that is not too fast to permit a big amount of transfer information.

is there any other tips related to implement class and objects to perform on Eclipse Proyect, I will Thank You.

Comment: In this answer, you do give some information on the issue, but you're really not answering the question, which was how to go about finding a bluetooth RFID reader that is compatible with Android. Try to focus on answering the question, and open a new question if you think of one.