# RFID Reader for Mobile Devices

Tags: android, iphone, mobile, bluetooth, rfid

I've been asked to develop an app with the core functionality of reading RFID chips in pets and checking those identification numbers against a database through some web service.

I was first directed towards [iCarte](http://www.icarte.ca/), supposed maker of an NFC/RFID Reader accessory for iPhone. I sent them an email that was immediately returned due to them exceeding their mailbox quota, so I suppose they are out of business?

Other solutions come in the form of Bluetooth ready readers, like those from [Serialio](https://serialio.com/). Demos show data being read into iOS's Notes app or some grid app. I haven't developed iPhone apps in a while... is the [Bluetooth API](http://dedegroup.tumblr.com/post/14177518904/bluetooth) available? How about for Android? Could I read from the Bluetooth reader straight into an app?

What other options are there?

Comment: There is a bluetooth API for Android, and you can read the data in an app

Comment: take a look at [my answer](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13751830/wireless-rfid-tag-reader)! And check the IDBlue link.

Comment: I recently found this: https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=se.anyro.nfc_reader (sourcecode available: https://github.com/nadam/nfc-reader).  It works on my contactless debit card, but didn't work on a stray we recently found (though we're not sure whether she's chipped; so not sure if that's the app or just lack of chip).  If you do develop something, please say here: http://pets.stackexchange.com/questions/10504/is-there-an-app-to-say-if-a-pets-chipped/10505 - as others may be looking for your app.

Answer (score 5):

Before you start any work please familiarize yourself with this:

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_11784_%26_11785

and this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_14223

RFIDs for animals are completely different protocol than NFC. It is more like UNIQUE tags (125kHz) . Anyway above ISO standards will be a good starting point for you.

Comment: These 125Khz RFIDs are frequently called LF RFID (low frequency) while the NFC standard uses 13.5Mhz RFIDs frequently called HF RFID (high frequency). Smartphones today often support HF RFID like the NFC, but rarely or never support LF RFID, so you'll need some middleman device that reads/writes LF RFID and communicates the information to your smartphone. You could try checking out something like this one: https://www.grabba.com/technologies/low-frequency

Answer (score 4):

Android have native support for NFC, you don't need any bluetooth adapter or anything else:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/connectivity/nfc/index.html

Not all devices have it, but the major ones do have (e.g. galaxy nexus, nexus 4, galaxy S3, HTC One) and it works nice.

Comment: I forgot to show you examples so you can see for yourself https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=at.mroland.android.apps.nfctaginfo I have this app and it reads fine my London public transport pass aka: Oyster Card (It's a Mifare 1K NFC tag).

Answer (score 0):

Passive RFID tags primarily operate at three frequency ranges:

- Low Frequency (LF) 125 -134 kHz
- High Frequency (HF)13.56 MHz
- Ultra High Frequency (UHF) 856 MHz to 960 MHz

Smartphones today often support HF RFID